# Leer campo blob de MySQL y convertilo a JSON para webservice android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, blob

Estoy creando un webservice para Android, en el que tengo que leer un campo blob de una base de datos MySQL. El problema es que no consigo codificar ese campo a JSON, que es el formato que luego necesitaré para leer el webservice con Android.

A ver si alguien sabe qué estoy haciendo mal.
Este es mi webservice con PHP:

```
<?php 

require('../../conect/conect.php');


$dbh -> exec("set names utf8");


$res=$dbh->query("select cast(mensaje as char(10000) character set utf8) mensa from ges_mensajes where cod_destino=4;");


$datos = array();

foreach ($res as $row) {

    $datos[] = $row;

}

//print_r($datos);  //Si ejecuto esta línea me sale bien por pantalla

echo json_encode($datos);


?>
```

He intentado castearlo a char, sin castearlo... el caso es que si imprimo con print_r me salen los datos por pantalla, pero al codificarlo a JSON, no me sale nada.

Y así es como lo leo desde Android:

```
public void ObtMensaje_volley(){

       ArrayList<String> mensaje = new ArrayList<>();
        String url = "https://local.es/WS_neton/obt_mensaje_blob.php";

        StringRequest eventfulRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {

                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);


                            String mensajeM;


                            for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){


                                mensajeM = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("mensa");
                                mensaje.add(mensajeM);

                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mensaje: "+String.valueOf(mensajeM), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //Log.e("Error: ", error.toString());
                    }
                });

        VolleySingleton.getInstance(this)
                .addToRequestQueue(eventfulRequest);
    }
```

Comment: que sale si haces el `echo json_encode($datos)`

Comment: No sale nada por pantalla, me aparece en blanco. Sin embargo, con print_r si veo los datos por pantalla. Lo cual me tiene confundido.

Comment: y si hace `var_dump($datos);exit();`

Comment: Sí, también me sale bien. Al igual que con print_r($datos)

Comment: `echo json_encode($output , JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);`

Comment: Lo intenté, pero no funciona tampoco. Por si sirve de algo, android me devuelve este error: "W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of ". Aunque no sé si es un fallo que estoy cometiendo en el php o en android :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me autorespondo a mi mismo, ya que después de muchas vueltas encontré una solución aceptable.
El error está en la sentencia SQL, que previamente hay que castearla a un juego de caracteres, en este caso latin 1.
Quedaría así:

```
$res=$dbh->query("select CONVERT(CAST(mensaje as BINARY) USING latin1) as mensa from ges_mensajes where cod_destino=4;");
```

Lo que devuelve un json capaz de reconocer caracteres y etiquetas html. Ya sólo resta leer el webservice en android con un WebView, por ejemplo, que reconocerá los caracteres extraños y las imágenes en base64.